# How to Upgrade MariaDB 10.* to the new version 11.* in CWP Panel in Centos 7?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7, cwp

Modify repo file to the version you want to upgrade

Edit File: /etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo

[mariadb]

name = MariaDB

baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.2/centos7-amd64

gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB

gpgcheck=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check which version of MariaDB is installed on your server**

MariaDB Repository Changes

Modify repo file to the version you want to upgrade

Edit File: /etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo

[mariadb]

name = MariaDB

baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.2/centos7-amd64

gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB

gpgcheck=1

Modify 10.2 with the version you want to upgrade

**Example for upgrade to MariaDB 11.3.2**

[mariadb]
name = MariaDB

baseurl = https://mirror.mariadb.org/yum/11.3.2/centos7-amd64/

gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB

gpgcheck=1

Stop and remove the old version of MariaDB (Databases will not be removed)

service mysql stop

service mariadb stop

systemctl disable mariadb

rpm --nodeps -ev MariaDB-server

Install the new version of MariaDB

yum clean all

yum -y update "MariaDB-*"

yum -y install MariaDB-server

systemctl enable mariadb

service mariadb start

mysql_upgrade